# Error messages in Python board game - defining global variables

Tags: python, error-handling, grid

Hey, I'm making a board game in python and i'm having a bit of trouble with the errors

For example:

```
ERROR_MOVE_CANT = "Error: %s %s can't move in direction %s" %(player, piece, direction)
```

When I try and raise this error later in my program I use:

```
if board[newch[1]][newch[0]] != '.':
    return ((ERROR_MOVE_CANT)%(player, piece, direction))
```

I get an error `"NameError: global name 'player' is not defined"`

I have previously defined 'player' to be either "Letter" or "number" but how do I define it as a global variable?

Comment: you should remove all your <br> and use the code formating option (the {} button ;) )

Answer (score 0):

global is merely the last place that is looked; you probably want to make it a local variable when you are using it, or correctly refer to it if it is an instance variable: `self.player`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably set the error message inside a function, creating a local variable instead of a global one:

```
def f():
    ERROR = 17
    # this variable is local to f

def g():
    global ERROR
    ERROR = 17
    #now the ERROR in this function is the global one.
```

---

(Btw, think twice before using global variables they most likely aren't the cleanest solution for your problem.)